# Samsung Series 7 backlit keyboard issue on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, backlight

After installing Win 10, my Samsung Series 7 backlit keyboard won't light up. 
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd> won't work and neither will <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for Samsung settings. I tried installing the Samsung software controlling this Easy Settings but it isn't supported in Win 10. No drivers available from Samsung, either. Is there a way to light it up?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got Samsung Settings working on an older Samsung "Chronos" laptop (model NP700Z7C-S01, buyed in 2012 and afterwards upgraded to Windows 10), but it should work on all Samsung laptops which don´t get Samsung Settings on a comfortable way with the Samsung Update tool:

1.) download and unzip Samsung Settings version 2.1.0.20 from here: http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=SUP&CDCttType=SW&ModelType=N&ModelName=SUP&idyn=N&VPath=SW/201307/20130726112522769/BASW-84270A23.ZIP

2.) run the command prompt as administrator and run "Inst.exe" from the downloaded package

Answer (score 0):

Exact same situation for me, I upgraded my Samsung series 7 laptop to Windows 10 from Windows 7.

Unfortunately, the backlit settings could only be used through easy settings, a Samsung application which isn't compatible with Windows 10, so it means no, Windows 10 renders the backlit keyboard useless and there's no way around it unless you downgrade back to Windows 7 and install easy settings.

That being said, I think the features and fresh design of Windows 10 makes up for this.

Also, Windows 10 may well release a compatibility for the backlit keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I succeded with this advice - it seems that Windows 10 recognize Samsung's built-in keyboard as Lenovo keybaord and then the backlighting starts working only sometimes. Reinstalling it as generic keyboard should fix the problem.

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/282684/No+backlight+in+keyboard+after+upgrading+to+windows+10